# How to parameterize styles?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm new in WPF. I'm trying to do same styles. The idea is to have a button style customizable. So, for example, i would like to change the background color of the button. or the image of the button.

Here is the code of the style

```
<Application
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity" xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
    x:Class="WPFControlsApp.App"
    StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <!-- Resources scoped at the Application level should be defined here. -->
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Simple Styles.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ControlTemplate x:Key="CustomButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    <Storyboard x:Key="CuandoEstoyArribaDelBoton">
                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Glow">
                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White"/>
                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.7" Value="#FF562020"/>
                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                <Grid>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="Background" Fill="#FF5A98EB" RadiusY="15" RadiusX="15" Stroke="#FF114FA1" StrokeThickness="2"/>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="Glow" Fill="White" RadiusY="15" RadiusX="15" Stroke="{x:Null}" StrokeThickness="0" Margin="0,0,0,49" Opacity="0.215"/>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="Glass" RadiusY="15" RadiusX="15" Stroke="#FF114FA1" StrokeThickness="2" Opacity="0.475">
                        <Rectangle.Fill>
                            <RadialGradientBrush RadiusY="0.62" RadiusX="0.62" GradientOrigin="0.506,1.063">
                                <GradientStop Color="#00000000" Offset="0"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#FF00084B" Offset="1"/>
                            </RadialGradientBrush>
                        </Rectangle.Fill>
                    </Rectangle>
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" Content="{Binding MINOMBREBOTON, FallbackValue=MiBoton}"/>
                    <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="7,24,0,25" Width="100" Source="{Binding BtnImageSource}"/>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True"/>
                    <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="True"/>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Trigger.ExitActions>
                            <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="CuandoEstoyArribaDelBoton_BeginStoryboard"/>
                        </Trigger.ExitActions>
                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard x:Name="CuandoEstoyArribaDelBoton_BeginStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource CuandoEstoyArribaDelBoton}"/>
                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True"/>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

here is the problem i don´t know how to solve

```
<Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="7,24,0,25" Width="100" Source="{Binding BtnImageSource}"/>
```

I have a binding named BtnImageSource. But i don´t know how to set it in button definition.

```
<Button Content="Salir" Height="102" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,25,26" Name="btn_salir" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="280" ClipToBounds="False" Click="btn_salir_Click" Style="{StaticResource CustomButtonStyle}" />
```

Do you know how can i have 3 o 4 buttons each one with the same style but different images?

This is a test for a new app. The idea is to use styles with parameters or find another alternative.

Thanks in advance. I hope be clear.

Comment: hey there i think you can use expression blend for the same where you can make changes to the look and feel of your application easily. hope it is helpful for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes thats possible.... `DynamicResource` should help. Set the color properties to some `DynamicResource` (with a resource key). This Key may not exist at the time of declaration. Then when you need a specific color, then create a Brush of that color and declare it **same** `Key` and merge with the relevant resource.

E.g. you have this style resource that uses a dynamic color brush `DynamicColorBrush` to set to a button's background...

```
<App.Resources ...>
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Background="{DynamicResource DynamicColorBrush}" />
 </Style>
....
```

Note that `App.Resources` does not have `DynamicColorBrush` defined. Now suppose you define buttons in two different views

```
<UserControl ... x:Class="UserControl1">
     <UserControl.Resources>
          <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DynamicColorBrush" Color="Red"/>
     </UserControl.Resources>
     <Grid><Button Content="Red Button"/></Grid>
</UserControl>
```

and

```
<UserControl ... x:Class="UserControl2">
     <UserControl.Resources>
          <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DynamicColorBrush" Color="Green"/>
     </UserControl.Resources>
     <Grid><Button Content="Green Button"/></Grid>
</UserControl>
```

This should work.

The whole concept of flexi themes where runtime base color change is allowed is done using the dynamic resource concept.